# How to call function every 2 seconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out How to call function every 2 seconds in Python? 
Should I use timer or thread?
Can anyone provide links/examples please?

Comment: Please provide some more detail as to the requirements. The approach will vary depending on the latency you can tolerate, how accurately the calls need to be spaced and whether you can tolerate any missed calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) module can do that:

```
import sched, time
schedTimer = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def increaseX(x):
    x += 1
    print('X increased to ' + str(x))
    schedTimer.enter(2, 1, increaseX, (x,))
schedTimer.enter(2, 1, increaseX, (3,))
schedTimer.run()
```